# could t-test be used to calculate how much differences for two statistics?

Tags: statistics

We know t-test could be used to test whether two statistics has significant differences. My question is, could t-test be used to test how much differences are two statistics? For example, whether t-test could answer question like "two statistics has 10% differences with p-value 0.05"?

If t-test could do this, appreciate if anyone could share a bit more details. :-)

regards,
Lin

Comment: Probably stats questions will be better answers here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnM, nice reference, vote up.